# How to group by 1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

How can I `group by 1` in SQL Server?

I have alot of SQL sum from Oracle need change to SQL Server. In sum column oracle they has been group by 1. But in Sql Server group by 1 false.
For example

```
Create table MyTable(
    PRICE int 
)
go;

select SUM(PRICE) as Total 
from MyTable
```

Result return 1 row null.

In Oracle they have been group by 1 like this:

```
select SUM(PRICE) as Total 
from MyTable
group by 1
```

Return no row.

How can I do it in Sql Server?

Comment: Use the original column name instead of `1` index

Comment: Adding the column name to `select` will make the result more meaningful.

Comment: Since you don't have any other columns in your `SELECT` other than the `SUM`, there's absolutely no point in grouping..... what are you trying to do, really??

Comment: For example when you whan get total money from one table, how can you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql Server <= 2012, As fa as i known . It not support GROUP by 1. But you can try sql like this will is the same.
--- Create 1 table example

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 int
);
```

--- Return 1 row if data is null:

```
select sum(column1) as total 
from table_name
```

--- Return 0 row if data null <=> Oracle group by 1

```
select sum(column1) as total 
from(
select column1, 1 as GroupBy  from table_name
) a
group by GroupBy
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by 1 is not supported in SQL Server but you can put the same code like this:

```
select SUM(PRICE) as Total 
from MyTable
having count(PRICE) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `GROUP BY` is

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table_name
WHERE [ conditions ]
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

Condition(`WHERE`) is optional.

Comment: I just want sum 1 column and don't need to Group by any column, thanks